# Do unupdated qualifiers still get evicted in hbase?

Tags: hbase

I could not find this in their documentation. Here's an example:

Say I have an Hbase table with one column family, f, with maxVersions set to 2 and have data with 2 qualifiers, q1 and q2. I add a row r1 to it and now I have:

```
r1=>f:q1:ts1 ("some data 1")
r1=>f:q2:ts1 ("some data 2")
```

After that I execute put r1=>f:q1 ("other data") twice. From what I understood, "some data 1" from q1 qualifier will then be deleted because two new versions were written to q1. But what happens to qualifier q2? Does it's data get deleted because I added two new versions of the row, or does it remain because there is just one version of it (I added data to q1 only)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off HBase does not immediately delete old versions - they'll only be removed in compactions. Most operations will mask old versions (that exceed the max versions) but not all see [JIRA-10102](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-10102) for example.

Regarding your questions q2 won't be affected. The versions are managed at per qualifier instance. You can easely try that in the `hbase shell` :

```
create 't1', {NAME => 'f', VERSIONS => 1}
put 't1', 'r1', 'f:q1', 'some data 1', 1000
put 't1', 'r1', 'f:q2', 'some data 2', 1000
put 't1', 'r1', 'f:q1', 'other data', 2000
scan 't1'
```